# Debounce function not firing in Cucumber.js & Zombie.js feature test

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, bdd, zombie.js

I have a feature test that tests the following

```
Given I am on "search" listing
When I search for "31380" by "instance-id"
Then "1" "orders" are shown
```

The #instance-id input has a debounce function tied to it which after 250ms of no changes runs a function that changes the url.

Problem is that the URL in the Zombie browser never changes.

```
this.When(/^I search for "([^"]*)" by "([^"]*)"$/, async function(value, input) {
  this.browser.fill('#${input}', value);

  await this.waitForURLChange();

  console.log(this.browser.location.href); // yields http://localhost:3000/search instead of http://localhost:3000/search?ids=31380

  return this.browser.assert.url({ query: { ids: value } });
});
```

The waitForURLChange function has an interval that checks for a different URL every second for 4 seconds. After that it returns true. So it's safe to say that the URL hasn't changed in 4 seconds after the input was changed.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question but just wanted to suggest against using Cucumber to describe such low level operations. Cucumber should be focusing on a business/behavior side of an application while being maximally decoupled from the implementation.

Comment: @EugeneS not sure if I get what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Don't describe implementation details with Cucumber (e.g. When I search for "31380" by `instance-id`).

Comment: @EugeneS Thats literally whats on the Cucumber readme on their github, care to explain your reasoning?

Comment: This is what I tried to do in my first comment. Just Google "Cucumber best practices" (e.g. https://blog.codeship.com/cucumber-best-practices/) or even better grab a book. Generally, Cucumber is a BDD tool (Behavior Driven Development). It is designed to describe application features in a human readable format as well as serve as a "living documentation". Hence describing low level operation should be avoided (have a look at the "Write declarative features" which is part 1 in the article that I sent you in the link).